Как запустить метод перед исполняемым классом с тестами? (аннотации junit @Before не подходят)
Всем привет. Есть класс запуска тестов CucumberRunnerTest. Перед его запуском мне нужно запустить другую функцию, которая генерирует сценарии из других файлов в директорию, которая указана в feature (изначально она пустая)
package ru.cucumber.test;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/scenarios",
        glue = "ru/cucumber/test/stepDefinition"
)
public class CucumberRunnerTest {
}

После того, как я запускаю mvn clean test нужно правило, что перед CucumberRunnerTest сгенерировать сценарии, используя другой мой метод
Аннотации @Before, @BeforeClass, @BeforeAll не подходят, тк они запускаются после инициализации класса CucumberRunnerTest. Поэтому получается, что параметр feature указывает на пустую директорию, где нет сгенерированных файлов

Если все собирается мавеном то можно написать плагин. Еще можно перейти на JUnit5 и написть Extension

@talex да, уже понял, что нужно вызывать метод через мавен. Смог вызвать эту функцию через объявление класса main в плагине щапуска и запуском команды через отдельную дополнительную команду java exec:java. А вот как вызвать без дополнительных команд принудительно перед mvn test пока не получилось, сталкиваюсь с ошибкой, вот тут её описал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1588566/. Буду рад, если есть какие-то мысли по этому поводу

Для того чтобы вызывалось автоматически там можно execution настроить.

Нужно добавить что-то вроде                <executions>                     <execution>                         <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>                     </execution>                 </executions>

@talex заработало в такой конфигурации: <executions><execution><phase>generate-test-sources</phase><goals><goal>java</goal></goals></execution></executions>, спасибо за помощь!!
кстати, в предыдущем комментарии оставил неправильную ссылкку на вопрос) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1588894

class TestStackOwerflow {
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    }
}

в junit5 аннотации before не работают.
Вместо этой аннотации в Junit5 пишется аннотация BeforeEach с методом setUp(), который вызывается перед каждым тестируемым методом.
При создании теста спрашивается, создать ли его автоматически, или можно написать его самостоятельно.

Пробовал эту аннотацию тоже. С начала инициализируется класс CucumberRunnerTest, а затем всевозможные методы из аннотаций. Это видно, потому что ошибка явно указывает на то, что сценарии из директории feature не были найдены, то есть метод для их генерации не отработал
